# Gradle configuring TestNG and JUnit reports dirs

Tags: testing, junit, gradle

I am relatively new to gradle and we use both JUnit and testNG unit tests in our project. With google help I figured out how to make both testNG and JUnit tests running. Below is how I ended up by achieving it

```
build.gradle
....    
task testNG(type: Test) {
    useTestNG {}
}

test {
    dependsOn testNG
}
```

However only the JUnit reports are produced. Google again helped me with this link https://discuss.gradle.org/t/using-junit-and-testng-together-steps-on-testng-html-file/5484 which shows how to solve a problem that looks exactly like mine by configuring two separate test reports folders like below:

```
testng.testReportDir = file("$buildDir/reports/testng")
test.testReportDir = file("$buildDir/reports/testjunit")
```

However it does not exactly say where to put those two entries and I feel like I am going to get crazy trying to look at gradle books, gradle examples and API without figuring out how to. According with the API `test` task has a `reports` property where you can configure `TestTaskReports` instance but whatever I tried failed.
Can you please help me with this. It must be something so obvious that I am missing it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the DSL reference for [Test](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test). There you can find a `reports` property at https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:reports
This gives you a [TestTaskReports](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestTaskReports.html). Following this [route](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/reporting/ConfigurableReport.html#setDestination(java.lang.Object)) in the DSL leads you to:

```
task testNG(type: Test) {
    useTestNG {}
    reports.html.destination = file("$buildDir/reports/testng")
}

test {
    reports.html.destination = file("$buildDir/reports/test")

    dependsOn testNG
}
```

Comment: It worked very well thanks. Looking at my original question I realize how close I was. I found the `TestTaskReports` API however reading the documentation for the getHtml() method **"A HTML report indicate the results of the test execution."** I didn't get any clue it was something I could further configure. Something learned to watch out in the future :-)